# can i add onclick event to library feature item

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-library

I want to deploy a custom library feature (which i still have to figure out how to create) to a farm and want to have an onclick event when a user tries to access or open the document that does some stuff on backend prior to opening. Is this possible. Can I add onclick event to a feature? Please advise.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using modern experience or classic experience?

Comment: 2016, sorry i forgot to mention. and i dont know enough about the types of experience so i assume classic?